# How can I find whether RF transmitter and receiver are not in range?

Tags: rf

Suppose I have a device A with RF transmitter and device B with RF receiver with range 10 meters.

Is there a way a A gets notified when B is out of range? Do we have to keep checking from A at regular interval that B is accepting signals or not?

Comment: An RF receiver doesn't have a range. An RF transmitter doesn't have a range but, together the setup up will have a range in free-space at a certain data rate at a certain temperature.

Comment: In a certain environment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have a transmitter at one end and a receiver at the other, there is no way for the transmitter to know that the receiver is out of range (or turned off).

You would need two-way communication between the points for the originator to know that the recipient received the transmission.

Comment: How can I enable two-way communication in RF world?

Comment: For two-way communication you need a transmitter and a receiver at each end. (A transmitter and receiver are often combined in one package and called a transceiver).